# Shrink polygon to a specific area by offsetting

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, euclidean-geometry, polygons

I have a 2D polygon that I want to shrink by a specific offset (A) to match a certain area ratio (R) of the original polygon. Is there a formula or algorithm for such a problem? I am interested in a simple solution for a triangle/quad but also a solution for complex polygons.

I attached an image for explanation. The original polygon is offset by A (equal-distant for each edge). A has to be chosen so that the new polygon has a specific area. In this example it should have half the area of the initial polygon.[image]

Answer (score 8):

I am afraid there is no truly simple solution, unless you ignore the complexities.
Just think of how you would shrink a sharp `V`-shape, like this:

      [image: V-shrink]
In the above, the offset was larger than the `V`-gap, and so the shape naturally
fractured into two disconnected regions. This issue arises even with a quadrilateral.

To delve into the topic more thoroughly,
see the result of Ron Wein's 2007 definitive Ph.D. thesis, described in this paper:

> "Exact and approximate construction of offset polygons."
>   ([ACM link](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1244883)).

[image: WeinFig3]

His work is implemented in CGAL ([CGAL manual link](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Straight_skeleton_2/index.html)), and now nicely described in this book:

> Fogel, Efi, Dan Halperin, and Ron Wein. *CGAL Arrangements and Their Applications: A Step-by-Step Guide*. Vol. 7. Springer, 2012.

Finally, if you want to skim over the complexities, here is a decade-old survey that is nevertheless useful as a high-level viewpoint: [survey link](http://fcacciola.50webs.com/Offseting%20Methods.htm).