# Is there a name for the level-sets of the signed distance function to a set in a metric space?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, terminology

$\newcommand \X {\mathcal{X}}$
$\newcommand \sd {d_{\rm sign}}$
Let $(\X, d)$ be a metric space and define the distance between a point $x \in \X$ and a set $S \subset X$ by $d(x,S) = \inf_{y \in S} d(x,y)$ and the signed distance to be 
$$
\sd(x,S) = \begin{cases}
  d(x,S) & \hbox{ if $x \not \in S$}\\
  -d(x,S^c) & \hbox{ if $x \in S$}
\end{cases}.
$$

For any $\sigma \in \mathbb{R}$, we can define $S_\sigma = \{x \in \X \,:\, \sd(x,S) \leq \sigma\}$. When $\sigma > 0$ this corresponds to enlarging the set $S$ and when $\sigma$ is negative, this corresponds to shrinking $S$. Is there a name for the set $S_\sigma$, and do these sets have well-known properties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although your context is broader, these level sets under
the Euclidean metric are known as
*offset polygons*.
Here is an image from [an earlier MO question/answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/150072/6094):

---

[image]

---

Another useful term in this context is the *Minkowski sum*, e.g.,
this PDF slide presentation by Andreas Bock: 
[Minkowski Sums and Offsets of Polygons](http://resources.mpi-inf.mpg.de/departments/d1/teaching/ss10/Seminar_CGGC/Slides/07_Bock_MS.pdf).

Comment: Awesome, thank you. I am also interested in the following operation: Fix some $\sigma > 0$ and map each set $S$ to the double-offset polygon $(S_{-\sigma})_\sigma$ where we first shrink it by a distance $\sigma$ and then enlarge it again. This has the effect of smoothing out any details of the set $S$ that are smaller than $\sigma$. Does this have a name?

Comment: @Travis: Interesting smoothing operation. Surely this must have been investigated, but I am not recalling references...

Comment: @Travis: This is a stretch, but I just remembered that one can smooth a shape using the *medial axis*: "Shape Smoothing Using Medial Axis Properties," ([journal link](http://www.computer.org/csdl/trans/tp/1986/04/04767815-abs.html)). And the medial axis is very much related to your $S_{-\sigma}$.